# Проблема с линковкой в c / c++

Tags: gcc, mingw, c++

Начинаю учить c++, поэтому проблема может быть совсем глупой, я это даже чувствую. 
Заключается в следующем. Ставлю DevCpp, качаю libcurl.a, вот исходник файла, звать его "main.c" Режим "plain C".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /* always cleanup */ 
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

При компиляции как из DevCpp, так и из compile.bat

```
@echo off
mingw32-gcc -I"D:\\_CPP_\\devpaks\\include" -c main.c -o "main.o" -DCURL_STATICLIB
mingw32-g++ main.o -o "pr2.exe" -L"D:\\_CPP_\\Dev-Cpp\\lib" -lcurl -lws2_32 -lwinmm
pause
```

(были оба gcc, оба g++ и вообще во всех вариантах, код на c++ тоже тестил)
выдает следующее:

> `D:\\_CPP_\\Dev-Cpp\\lib/libcurl.a(content_encoding.o)(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to 'inflateEnd'`
> `[ ... еще 5 с другими переменными ... ]`
> `collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`
> `Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .`

Две ночи гугления дали такой результат: линковка есть, переменная среды PATH в порядке (проверял), библиотека и заголовки с оф сайта. Перезагружался) Пробелов в путях нет. Hello world компилится нормально, но любая подключенная библиотека(poco, boost, clSockets) рушит программу.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

UPD: простите, winXP SP2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по тому, что не хватает [inflateEnd](http://refspecs.freestandards.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/zlib-inflateend-1.html), это означает, что надо залинковать ещё zlib

PS: то есть это значит, что надо ещё добавить **-lz** к опциям

Comment: Огромное спасибо!)
Единственное, теперь меня волнует, неужели я во ВСЕХ библиотеках игнорировал список зависимостей? =( Ладно, в следующий раз буду внимательней. Вы мне, между прочим, дверь открыли)

Comment: Рад за вас ;) Нужно внимательнее читать сообщение об ошибке: линкер совершенно чётко ведь сообщил причину, почему он не может выполнить свою работу. Оставалось просто найти, что такое этот inflateEnd и где он бывает.

Comment: А я до этого везде искал, но попадались переменные либо из библиотеки, либо системные вроде htons. Еще и конфликты между minGW и MSVC ( "undefined reference to 'getaddrbyname@5'", собаку mingw не понимает).
Видимо, путь был верный, но я рано сдался)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить ваш libcurl.a к проекту в Project Options -> Parameters.

Comment: Одной из попыток был code::blocks, и в нем, и в devcpp я добавлял библиотеку как в список библеотек по full/relative path, так и по командам линкера (-lcurl). Более того, ошибка выдается не на main.c, а на самой библиотеке.